# PHP page not loading; Wordpress taking over with 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue where when I try to load a certain .php page in my browser, on a domain with Wordpress installed, Wordpress is throwing a 404 instead of the page itself.

The problem page is:

http://healthysurprise.com/special/sign-up?product=healthy

You can see the analog page here (just remove '/special'):

http://healthysurprise.com/sign-up?product=healthy

The URL string is required for php to load the page dynamically. The page is "sign-up.php" and is in the directory. What am I missing?

Notes:
- wordpress is installed
- index.php loads fine in both locations
- it seems to be doing this regardless of what the directory is
- there was a WP page template named 'sign-up' previously but I just removed it

Here's my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)$ /$1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You have to link it to WordPress somehow... Read about the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Comment: I can't just load my own php pages? I moved the WP installation into /blog, why is it interfering with other pages on the domain? Also, index.php works in the subdirectory.

Comment: Check htaccess for any url rewrite.

Comment: I updated the question with my .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was in the .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)$ /$1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The top rules from Wordpress were mucking everything up. By removing or commenting them out, normal pages will load regardless of whether the user calls /foo or /foo.php

This is the working .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /blog/
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)$ /$1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```